# Cat's poop and pee smell has gotten very strong

Tags: cats, health, defecation, urination

My cat's poop and pee's smell is killing me. It's been over a year since she came to me and I've always cleaned her tray once a week and the smell wasn't bad. But lately I've had to clean her tray three times a week because of the smell. Her poop smells so strong it makes me gag even through her litter box (she has one of those which are covered from all Sides with a flap door thing).

Her pee smells different, I don't know how to explain it, but it's entirely a new smell and also very strong. She's around three years old, female, and hasn't been spayed or neutered (will neuter her very soon). Since she's under weight (around 3.6-4 kgs), I've changed her diet from mostly biscuits (Mera cat food and Brit Care) and sometimes Can food (Brit Care) to mostly canned food (Whiskas) and biscuits (Mera Cat Food). I changed her diet about a month ago but the smelly problem has only started last week. I'm a student and vets around here are very expensive. Can anybody tell me if it's her diet or some serious problem? Thanks in advance❤.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't cleaning her litter box often enough. Once a day is really the minimum for her health and to keep down odor. Since you find the odor intolerable, think of how she feels. She has likely picked up a UTI (urinary tract infection) from the dirty litter. She should be seen by a vet in order to check for this or any other malady which brought on the change you now notice. Antibiotics are likely needed. There are low-cost spay/neuter services most places. Check the internet for your area. It is imperative she be spayed ASAP.

Once she's scheduled for the vet (ASAP), you need to completely empty the litter box, clean with soapy water and a scouring pad. Rinse thoroughly with clean water. In a bucket or glass container, add a 1/8 of a cup chlorine bleach to a liter of hot water. Pour this solution into the now clean litter box and slosh it around a few times. Empty the liquid into the sink and rinse the litter box again with warm/hot water. Let air dry or dry thoroughly with paper towels. Refill the box with new litter, remembering to scoop out soiled matter AT LEAST ONCE PER DAY.

Comment: Cat litter boxes should be scooped every day as Mat said.  Think of them as a toilet.  Would you like to use a toilet that had urine and excrement sitting in it from the previous day? I'm surprised you managed to go three days let alone one week without scooping it.  Has she been going to the bathroom around your house/apartment? That's an indicator that her box is not clean enough.

Comment: When I first got her,I used to clean it everyday but realized that it wasn't needed. She's a very fussy cat and won't even eat in a bowl that is not properly clean.She's never given an indication that the tray was smelly to her.She always does her business in her tray except for a few times (I immediately cleaned her tray).Every time I clean the tray I use a toilet cleaning brush and also I bit of baking soda(helps with the smell).That's what puzzling me...if the tray was too dirty for her she wouldn't have used it and let me know.

Comment: I believe she is letting you know. Remove solid waste once each day and add a bit more litter.

Comment: I'll clean her tray more often...but I think I've figured it out. I'm still giving her the same food but different flavor. Things are back on track. Thank you everyone❤